# Passing variants/arrays as arguments for a function

Tags: vba, excel

Example code;

```
Sub functiontester()

Dim testdata As Variant
Dim answer As Long
Dim result1 As Long

testdata = Sheets("worksheet1").Range("E1:E2").Value

result1 = testfunction(testdata)

result2 = testfunction2(testdata(2, 1))

End Sub

Function testfunction(stuff As Variant) As Long

    testfunction = stuff(2, 1)

End Function

Function testfunction2(num As Long) As Long

    testfunction2 = num

End Function
```

So from my days in python I'd expect result1 & result2 to both run fine, however this is not the case in VBA and if you try to run this you get

"compile error: Byref argument type mismatch" from result2; which I assume has something to do with limits of calculating values inside arguments of functions

So my question is: is there an easy way to make result2 work so that the variant reference just resolves to the specified element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`testdata(2, 1)` likely will be of type Double, not Long.

You can use

```
CLng(testdata(2, 1))
```

to cast it to a Long.

So:

```
result2 = testfunction2(CLng(testdata(2, 1)))
```

should be fine

Answer (score 2):

`"compile error: Byref argument type mismatch"` Actually refers to the fact it won't *implicitly* convert the datatype for you, because `ByRef` arguments (the default) are expected to be *writeable*.  If converted arguments are written to , it gets lost when you return from the function/subroutine because the converted values are only temporary, they're not in any variable outside of the called function.

You can get around this complaint by making the receiving parameter `ByVal`which means that it shouldn't be writable anyway:

```
Function testfunction2(ByVal num As Long) As Long
```